# What is the actor saying

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english, acronyms

What is the actor talking about from 5:25 to 5:55. Especially [at 5:41](https://youtu.be/2Nwk2q9BFbU?t=339). "...make the mistake of showing my son..." YouTube subtitles aren't really helpful. He mentions something that is surprising.

[Natalie Portman & Jude Law Answer the Web's Most Searched Questions | WIRED](https://youtu.be/2Nwk2q9BFbU?t=320)

Comment: We cannot tell what the actor (or anyone else) is saying.

Comment: Since you have not provided a link to the video, we do not know what you are talking about, so it is impossible for us to answer your question. Please edit your question to include a link, and then we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning at 5:25, Jude Law is talking about movies where his character has died, and the different ways that has happened. Natalie Portman asks if any of his family members are ever upset to watch it. Around 5:41 he says "I did make the mistake of showing my son A.I. a little bit too young" (referring to a movie he was in titled [A.I. Artificial Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.I._Artificial_Intelligence)) and goes on to describe how his character gets pulled apart by magnets.